# GDB debugging error while using a third-party lib LVGL on STM32

Tags: gdb, stm32, visualgdb, lvgl

I am using a third-party graphic lib names LVGL on stm32,but i met a problem while debugging and it can run with no errors and download into the board successfully.I debug the problem by visualGDB on Visual Studio Community 2022.The problem appeals very confused.The debug error shows when I set a breakpoint on a file of the library and I do noting just waiting for a few minutes,then I click the next step button of the IDE to go in the function and then the error happened.Or if i debug for a long time,the error will show.I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Here is the error gdb logs from the VisualGDB command lines.The log is too long so I cut the error logs by comparing the correct one and the wrong one to get this log.
You can see i set a breakpoint on line 96 of file lv_task.c,then i just wait a few minutes and the error will happen when i click the next step debugger button.

```
^done,stack-args=[frame={level="0",args=[]},frame={level="1",args=[]},frame={level="2",args=[]},frame={level="3",args=[]}]
-stack-select-frame 0
^done
-thread-select 1
^done,new-thread-id="1",frame={level="0",addr="0x0801b824",func="lv_task_handler",args=[],file="../User_code/Lvgl/lvgl/src/lv_misc/lv_task.c",fullname="D:\\LVGLWork\\Module_gui\\Project\\User_code\\Lvgl\\lvgl\\src\\lv_misc\\lv_task.c",line="96",arch="armv7e-m"}
-exec-next
^running
*running,thread-id="all"
*stopped,reason="end-stepping-range",frame={addr="0x053ef158",func="??",args=[],arch="armv7e-m"},thread-id="1",stopped-threads="all"
-data-list-register-values r-10
^done,register-values=[{number="0",value="0x053ef158"},{number="1",value="0x053ef158"},{number="2",value="0x053ef158"},{number="3",value="0x053ef158"},{number="4",value="0x053ef158"},{number="5",value="0x053ef158"},{number="6",value="0x053ef158"},{number="7",value="0x053ef158"},{number="8",value="0x053ef158"},{number="9",value="0x053ef158"},{number="10",value="0x053ef158"},{number="11",value="0x053ef158"},{number="12",value="0x053ef158"},{number="13",value="0x053ef158"},{number="14",value="0x053ef158"},{number="15",value="0x053ef158"},{number="25",value="0x053ef158"},{number="91",value="0x02570000"},{number="92",value="0x053eaf30"},{number="93",value="0x00000000"},{number="94",value="0x00000000"},{number="95",value="0x00000000"},{number="96",value="0x00000000"},{number="97",value="0x053eaf30"},{number="98",value="0x00000000"},{number="99",value="0x00000000"},{number="100",value="0x00000000"},{number="101",value="0x00000000"},{number="102",value="0x00000000"},{number="103",value="0x00000000"},{number="104",value="0x00000000"},{number="105",value="0x00000000"},{number="106",value="0x00000000"},{number="107",value="0x00000000"},{number="108",value="0x00000000"},{number="109",value="0x00000000"},{number="110",value="0x00000000"},{number="111",value="0x00000000"},{number="112",value="0x00000000"},{number="113",value="0x00000000"},{number="114",value="0x00000000"},{number="115",value="0x00000000"},{number="116",value="0x00000000"},{number="117",value="0x00000000"},{number="118",value="0x00000000"},{number="119",value="0x00000000"},{number="120",value="0x00000000"},{number="121",value="0x00000000"},{number="122",value="0x00000000"},{number="123",value="0x00000000"},{number="124",value="0x00000000"},{number="125",value="0x00000000"},{number="126",value="0x00000000"},{number="127",value="0x00000000"},{number="128",value="0x00000000"},{number="129",value="0x00000000"},{number="130",value="0x0000000000000000"},{number="131",value="0x0000000000000000"},{number="132",value="0x0000000000000000"},{number="133",value="0x0000000000000000"},{number="134",value="0x0000000000000000"},{number="135",value="0x0000000000000000"},{number="136",value="0x0000000000000000"},{number="137",value="0x0000000000000000"},{number="138",value="0x0000000000000000"},{number="139",value="0x0000000000000000"},{number="140",value="0x0000000000000000"},{number="141",value="0x0000000000000000"},{number="142",value="0x0000000000000000"},{number="143",value="0x0000000000000000"},{number="144",value="0x0000000000000000"},{number="145",value="0x0000000000000000"}]
-stack-list-frames --thread 1
^done,stack=[frame={level="0",addr="0x053ef158",func="??",arch="armv7e-m"}]
-stack-list-arguments --thread 1 0
^done,stack-args=[frame={level="0",args=[]}]
info symbol 0x53ef157
&"info symbol 0x53ef157\n"
~"No symbol matches 0x53ef157.\n"
^done
info symbol 0x53ef155
&"info symbol 0x53ef155\n"
~"No symbol matches 0x53ef155.\n"
^done
info symbol 0x53ef14e
&"info symbol 0x53ef14e\n"
~"No symbol matches 0x53ef14e.\n"
^done
info symbol 0x53ef0f4
&"info symbol 0x53ef0f4\n"
~"No symbol matches 0x53ef0f4.\n"
^done
x/31i 0x53ef158
&"x/31i 0x53ef158\n"
~"=> 0x53ef158:\t"
&"Cannot access memory at address 0x53ef158\n"
^error,msg="Cannot access memory at address 0x53ef158"
x/31i 0x53ef158
&"x/31i 0x53ef158\n"
~"=> 0x53ef158:\t"
&"Cannot access memory at address 0x53ef158\n"
^error,msg="Cannot access memory at address 0x53ef158"
```

I have tried find the GDB handscripts to find out what happend in the program.In my limited experience with the GDB debugging,I am confused by the complex GDB command.The visual studio just gives me a memory access error,what should i do in the next step?